# How to insert data with the WPDB insert method in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins

I tried to insert data in the form array in the database table but it's not working. Could anyone help me solve this?

```php
function my_plugin_activation(){
    global $wpdb , $table_prefix;

    $wp_card = $table_prefix.'card';

    $q = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` $wp_card` (`ID` INT NOT NULL , `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
    `Email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , `status` BOOLEAN NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ) ENGINE = InnoDB;";
    $wpdb -> query($q);

    $data = array(
        'name'=> 'pankaj',
        'email' => 'pankajchhabra06@gmail.com',
        'status' => 1,
    );

      $wpdb->insert('wp_card',$data);

   /** $wpdb->insert($wp_card ,$data);  */
   

}
```

Comment: Please attach error details. Also better to have some description about expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The primary key "ID" value is missing. Or you can set it as auto Increment field.

Comment: I have already tried this by adding Id key and value but still it's not working

Comment: print the sql query and check